# How to change the record posisiton in a smart way in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, record

I came across a problem in MySQL record order. My problem is that I would like a record to be right before another one, but actually the record I wanna "move-up" is under other records. This is the table:

```
id | column1
 1 | Residents
 2 | In age from 0 to 6  
 3 | In age from 6 to 14 
 4 | In age from 14 to 30 
 5 | In age from 30 to 66  
 6 | Total school population
 7 | Students in kindergarten
 8 | Students in high school
 9 | Other record 
10 | ...
11 | ...
12 | 66 years and over
```

I would like the 12th record to be right after the 5th, thus right after "In age from 30 to 66". Is there a smart way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Introduce the `integer` `order` column and modify it as necessary

Comment: MySQL doesn't keep track of record order. If you care about the order of output, you need to use an `ORDER BY` clause, and include some data in the table that provides ordering criteria.

Comment: All right, I was thinking about something like that. but then I have to recover this data from the db and see displayed in a web page, associated to the proper master data, e.g. Residents, In age from 0 to 6, In age from 6 to 14, 66 years and over -- are all details of the master "Population", while "Total school population" and co. are all details of "Education", how can I be sure that when I recover the data they will be ordered as I want?

Answer (score 0):

There is no order or position of rows in a RDBMS table. SQL queries do not claim or guarantee to return rows in any predictable order, except that which you specify in an ORDER BY clause of the query.

So if you have a desired order in which you want to see the rows, you should have some column in the table which you can specify in an ORDER BY clause. Then reordering rows consists of changing the values in this column.

You can do this with ALTER TABLE

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ORDER BY columnname ASC;.
```

but be aware that the table does not remain in this order after inserts and deletes

or you can simply select it...

```
SELECT *  FROM tablename ORDER BY columnname DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN columnname REGEXP '[0-9]' Then 0 Else 1 End,ID Asc
```

Comment: Sorry,, what does this sql statement?

Comment: It will find the columnName which contain Numbers and then order it by id....@user3019105

Comment: the WHNE is a clause or something?

Comment: ITS CASE STATEMENT....Refer the link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: Ah it's WHEN not WHNE, now I understand

Comment: @user3019105 am sorry, now i changed